# Find a percentage relation between two string according to their context

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-scraping

I'm implementing a web scraper for html pages. The problem is the context relation as I need to decide the relation between the content I got and the others in the DB so I can say yes they are related or not as context point of view :

Ex( 1 )

```
$str1 = "president obama visited Barcelona yesterday"; //politics context
$str2 = "Barcelona was defeated from Chelsea yesterday"; //sports context
```

Ex( 2 )

```
$str3 = "Obama's appearance on Late Night With Jimmy Fallon "; //media context
$str4 = "Late Night show with jimmy fallon"; //mdeia context
```

In the First example

> **$str1** and **$str2** are different in context so relation may be **10%** or less

In the Second example

> **$str3** and **$str4** are in the same context (media) although $str3 about president obama and the **$str4** about Jimmy Fallon but both are related to late night show,So relation may be **90%**

I'm using the Porter-Stemmer algorithm to remove the common endings from words. What to do next?

Comment: Sorry, but what's the actual question? You need a generic description of an algorithm, or just some advice on how implement your ideas in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Any thing would be appreciated specially a statistical method or algorithm to detect this relation

Answer (score 1):

The keywords are string metrics, fuzzy matching...

Take a look this: [How to Strike a Match](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/StrikeAMatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$exstr1=explode(" ", $str1);
$exstr2=explode(" ", $str2);
foreach( $exstr1 as $exitem)
{
     if (in_array($exitem, $exstr2 ) $match++;
      else $mis++;
}
$percent=$match/($match+$mis)*100;
```